# text of the first line disappears after using rowcolors

Tags: tables, color, multicolumn, multirow, rowcolor

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}


\begin{table*}
\rowcolors{1}{yellow!50}{yellow!30}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

\caption{Related Surveys Comparison}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{l|} X | X | l |}
\hline

\multirow{5}{*}[-1.5ex]{\rx{Paper}} & 
\multirow{5}{3.5cm}[-1.5ex]{\centering Scope} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Topics} & 
\multirow{6}{4cm}[-1.5ex]{\centering Contribution} & 
\multirow{5}{4cm}[-1.5ex]{\centering Drawbacks} & 
\multirow{5}{*}[-1.5ex]{\rx{Year}} \\ 
\cline{3-7}
 &  &  
\rx{Architect.\ Design} & 
\rx{Mobility} & 
\rx{Security} & 
\rx{Privacy} & 
\rx{~Detect.\ and Prev.~} & & & \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{139}}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil VFC environment} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC architecture  
  \item Security issues in VFC 
\end{myitemize}   &    
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Security solutions in VFC
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \rx{2019}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{142}}}  &  
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil VEC environment} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item V2V and V2I in VEC 
  \item Security and privacy in VEC 
\end{myitemize}  &    
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC and VEC comparison 
  \item VEC security requirements 
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \rx{2019}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{143}}} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\hfil Fog Computing in VANET} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Connecting vehicles to VANET
  \item Security and forensics requirements  
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Vehicles as Fog nodes 
  \item Possible scenarios in VFC 
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC  
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\rx{2017}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{146}}}  &    
\multirow{3}{*}{\hfil VFC application}  & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC: Video crowdsourcing 
  as a study case     
\end{myitemize} &  
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Security and privacy challenges 
  \item Countermeasures for mitigation in VFC  
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \rx{2018}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{149}}} &    
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil Fog Computing in VANET} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Integration of Fog Computing in VANET 
\end{myitemize}   &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Deployment on vehicles as fog nodes 
  \item VFC applications     
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2017}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{145}}} &       
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil VFC challenges} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC taxonomy vehicles deployment in VFC     
\end{myitemize}  &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC implementation requirements 
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC  
\end{myitemize}  & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2020}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{147}}}  &  
\multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \makecell[l]{Dissemination of Data \\ in VFC}} & 
\multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
  VCC vs VFC in: 
  
  \begin{myitemize} 
  \item Data Dissemination 
  \item Applications 
  \item Security threats   
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Privacy issues in VFC 
  \item Misbehaving detection and prevention solutions   
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{4}{*}{\hfil \rx{2021}} \\ 
\hline
%after reviewers' response

\multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{191}}}  &  
\multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \makecell[l]{VFC: implementation and \\ open issues} }& 
\multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
  
  \begin{myitemize} 
  \item Identifies challenges related to VFC: \\ resource allocation,  communication protocols, security, energy, and mobility. 
  \item Analyzes various task offloading techniques in VFC.
  \item Evaluates strengths and limitations, \\ considering suitability for different scenarios.
  \item Provides insights for improvement and innovation in VFC.   
\end{myitemize} &   


Security and Privacy Concerns:
 \begin{myitemize} 
 \item Briefly addresses, lacks depth. 
  \item Ignores privacy-preserving techniques\\.
 \end{myitemize} 
 
Scalability of VFC:
\begin{myitemize}
   \item Inadequate discussion on scalability.
   \item Doesn't address challenges \\ with increasing data volume.
 \end{myitemize}
 & 
\multirow{11}{*}{\hfil \rx{2022}} \\ 
\hline

\multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \rx{\cite{190}}}  &  
\multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \makecell[l]{Task offloading in VFC}} & 
\multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \ding{55}} & 
  
  \begin{myitemize} 
  \item Addresses key challenges: resource allocation, security, energy, etc. 
  \item Introduces a structured framework for task offloading understanding. 
  \item valuates techniques, strengths, and limitations for varied scenarios.   
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Focused on task offloading; may miss broader insights from a wider scope. 
  \item May not include the latest advancements, potentially limiting relevance.  
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{6}{*}{\hfil \rx{2022}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\rx{Our survey}}  &    
\multirow{5}{*}{\hfil \makecell[l]{VFC: security and trust \\ issues}}  & 
\multirow{5}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\hfil \ding{51}} &  
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC global architecture 
  \item VFC implementation
  \item VFC scenarios 
  \item Security and privacy threats
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC   
\end{myitemize} & & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}


\label{tab: RelatedSurveys}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: please show a **small**  and **complete** example. That makes it much easier to test your code and to find your missing line.

Comment: Addig to Ulrike's comment: Please note that we don't know anything about the definitions you use in your code, such as `\rx` or `\begin{myitemize}`. Apart from that, why do you use `\multirow` that often? You only need to span at most two rows in the header section but not six, if I got your code right.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to answer, since you did not provide a complete MWE.

I think your problem is that you used `\multirow` in the first line, where you should not.

However, this is my suggestion using `tabularray`. It simplifies a lot the code, even if it slow your compilation.

The citations appear as `[?]` since you did not provide them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Invented, since you don't put them in your MWE:
\newcommand{\rx}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{#1}}
\newenvironment{myitemize}{\begin{itemize}[nosep,  leftmargin=8pt]}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={Related Surveys Comparison},
    label={tab:RelatedSurveys}
    ]{
    width={\textwidth}, 
    colspec={*{7}{Q[m,j]}X[m,j]X[m,j]Q[m,j]},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead = 2, rowfoot=0,
    row{odd} = {yellow!30},
    row{even} = {yellow!50},
    row{1} = {yellow!50},
    measure=vbox,stretch=-1,
    rowsep=4pt
    }
\SetCell[r=2]{c} \rx{Paper} & 
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Scope & 
\SetCell[c=5]{c} Topics & &&&&
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Contribution & 
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Drawbacks & 
\SetCell[r=2]{c} \rx{Year} \\ 
 &  &  
\rx{Architect.\ Design} & 
\rx{Mobility} & 
\rx{Security} & 
\rx{Privacy} & 
\rx{~Detect.\ and Prev.~} & & & \\ 
\rx{\cite{139}}& 
 VFC environment & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} &  \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC architecture  
  \item Security issues in VFC 
\end{myitemize}   &    
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Security solutions in VFC
\end{myitemize} & 
 \rx{2019} \\ 
 \rx{\cite{143}} & 
Fog Computing in VANET & 
\ding{51} &  \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} &  \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Connecting vehicles to VANET
  \item Security and forensics requirements  
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Vehicles as Fog nodes 
  \item Possible scenarios in VFC 
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC  
\end{myitemize} & 
\rx{2017} \\
\rx{\cite{146}}  &    
 VFC application  & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC: Video crowdsourcing 
  as a study case     
\end{myitemize} &  
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Security and privacy challenges 
  \item Countermeasures for mitigation in VFC  
\end{myitemize} & 
\rx{2018} \\
\rx{\cite{149}} &    
Fog Computing in VANET & 
 \ding{55} &  \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55}& 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Integration of Fog Computing in VANET 
\end{myitemize}   &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Deployment on vehicles as fog nodes 
  \item VFC applications     
\end{myitemize} & 
\rx{2017} \\ 
\rx{\cite{145}} &       
VFC challenges & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC taxonomy vehicles deployment in VFC     
\end{myitemize}  &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC implementation requirements 
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC  
\end{myitemize}  & 
\rx{2020} \\ 
\rx{\cite{147}}  &  
{Dissemination of Data \\ in VFC} & 
\ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
  VCC vs VFC in: 
  
  \begin{myitemize} 
  \item Data Dissemination 
  \item Applications 
  \item Security threats   
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Privacy issues in VFC 
  \item Misbehaving detection and prevention solutions   
\end{myitemize} & 
\rx{2021} \\ 
%after reviewers' response

\rx{\cite{191}}  &  
{VFC: implementation and \\ open issues}& 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
  
  \begin{myitemize} 
  \item Identifies challenges related to VFC: \\ resource allocation,  communication protocols, security, energy, and mobility. 
  \item Analyzes various task offloading techniques in VFC.
  \item Evaluates strengths and limitations, \\ considering suitability for different scenarios.
  \item Provides insights for improvement and innovation in VFC.   
\end{myitemize} &   


Security and Privacy Concerns:
 \begin{myitemize} 
 \item Briefly addresses, lacks depth. 
  \item Ignores privacy-preserving techniques\\.
 \end{myitemize} 
 
Scalability of VFC:
\begin{myitemize}
   \item Inadequate discussion on scalability.
   \item Doesn't address challenges \\ with increasing data volume.
 \end{myitemize}
 & 
\rx{2022} \\ 

\rx{\cite{190}}  &  
Task offloading in VFC & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
  
  \begin{myitemize} 
  \item Addresses key challenges: resource allocation, security, energy, etc. 
  \item Introduces a structured framework for task offloading understanding. 
  \item valuates techniques, strengths, and limitations for varied scenarios.   
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Focused on task offloading; may miss broader insights from a wider scope. 
  \item May not include the latest advancements, potentially limiting relevance.  
\end{myitemize} & 
\rx{2022} \\ 
\rx{Our survey}  &    
{VFC: security and trust \\ issues}  & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} &  
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC global architecture 
  \item VFC implementation
  \item VFC scenarios 
  \item Security and privacy threats
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC   
\end{myitemize} & & \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]